# Significant whitespace in SVG embedded in HTML

Tags: xml, svg, whitespace

I have svg embeded in html.

For svg embeded in html, ie&chrome do not support xml:space=preserve. so multiple " " will condense to one " ". replace " " with &nbsp will keep multiple " " and soleve the problem.

Are there any better way to do it? Thank you. please see example html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>

<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 1024 768" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
>

<text
x="0"
y="0"
id="textsvg"
font-family="Bitstream Vera Sans" 
font-size="100"
fill="black"
>

<tspan
x="0"
dy="100"
>
wel co     me vs wel&nbsp;co&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;me
</tspan>
</text>

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this SVG in HTML, or SVG in XHTML? Can you provide a simple test case showing your problem?

Comment: please see the example html. this is svg in html. Is there difference svg in html vs svg in xhtml? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /><title>Whitespace in SVG in HTML</title>
</head><body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <text font-size="10" fill="black">
    <tspan dy="10" xml:space="preserve">hi—h i—h  i—h     i</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
</body></html>
```

Even the SVG-in-XHTML version doesn't work in IE9:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Whitespace in SVG in HTML</title>
</head><body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <text font-size="10" fill="black">
    <tspan dy="10" xml:space="preserve">hi—h i—h  i—h     i</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this css property on the text element :

`text {
    white-space: pre;
}`